# Wordpress custam widget code is not working properly and did not find the problem/error in my code?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming

I am very thankful. If someone helps me on this. I am using the latest version of the WordPress. I am trying to create a widget that displays the company's name and contact information. from the code, I am able to add only one company detail but unable to add more companies details when I click on the add another company button, it is throwing a pop display that shows **leave site? Changes you made may not be saved**.
Here I am sharing the child theme functions.php file and custom-widget.php file. In the functions.php file in the last, I include the custom-widget.php file.

```
<?php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

// BEGIN ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
// AUTO GENERATED - Do not modify or remove comment markers above or below:

if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):
    function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array() );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 10 );

require_once('custom-widget.php');
// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
```

This is the custom-widget.php file code:

```
<?php
// Creating the widget 
/* Create Widget Start Here */
/**
 * Adds ContactInformation_Widget widget.
 */
class ContactInformation_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Register widget with WordPress.
     */
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'contactinformation_widget',
            __( 'Contact Information Widget', 'contact-information-widget' ),
            array( 'description' => __( 'Display your company name(s) and contact information.', 'contact-information-widget' ), )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Front-end display of widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::widget()
     *
     * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
     * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $output = '';
        echo $args['before_widget'];

        if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ) . $args['after_title'];
        }

        $company_names = isset( $instance['company_names'] ) ? $instance['company_names'] : array();
        $contact_emails = isset( $instance['contact_emails'] ) ? $instance['contact_emails'] : array();

        if ( ! empty( $company_names ) || ! empty( $contact_emails ) ) {
            $output .= '<div class="ciw_contactinformation">';
            foreach ( $company_names as $index => $company_name ) {
                if ( ! empty( $company_name ) || ! empty( $contact_emails[ $index ] ) ) {
                    $output .= '<div class="ciw_company_information">';
                    if ( ! empty( $company_name ) ) {
                        $output .= '<div class="ciw_company_name">
                                        <div class="ciw_company_name_text">' . $company_name . '</div>
                                    </div>';
                    }
                    if ( ! empty( $contact_emails[ $index ] ) ) {
                        $output .= '<div class="ciw_email">
                                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                        <div class="ciw_contact_email"><a href="mailto:' . $contact_emails[ $index ] . '" target="_blank">' . $contact_emails[ $index ] . '</a></div>
                                    </div>';
                    }
                    $output .= '</div>';
                }
            }
            $output .= '</div>';
        }

        echo $output;
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }
    /**

/**
     * Back-end widget form.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::form()
     *
     * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'Contact Us', 'contact-information-widget' );
        $company_names = isset( $instance['company_names'] ) ? $instance['company_names'] : array();
        $contact_emails = isset( $instance['contact_emails'] ) ? $instance['contact_emails'] : array();
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
        </p>
        <div id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'company_information' ); ?>">
            <?php
            if ( ! empty( $company_names ) || ! empty( $contact_emails ) ) {
                foreach ( $company_names as $index => $company_name ) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="ciw_company_information_container">
                        <label><?php echo __( 'Company Name:' ); ?></label>
                        <input class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'company_names' ); ?>[]" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $company_name ); ?>">
                        <label><?php echo __( 'Contact Email:' ); ?></label>
                        <input class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'contact_emails' ); ?>[]" type="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $contact_emails[ $index ] ); ?>">
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            } else {
                ?>
                <div class="ciw_company_information_container">
                    <label><?php echo __( 'Company Name:' ); ?></label>
                    <input class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'company_names' ); ?>[]" type="text" value="">
                    <label><?php echo __( 'Contact Email:' ); ?></label>
                    <input class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'contact_emails' ); ?>[]" type="email" value="">
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
<p>
    <button class="button add_new_company"><?php echo __( 'Add Another Company' ); ?></button>
</p>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var container = $('#<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'company_information' ); ?>');
        var addButton = container.find('.add_new_company');
        var index = <?php echo count( $company_names ); ?>;

        addButton.on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            index++;
            var companyInformation = '<div class="ciw_company_information_container">';
            companyInformation += '<label><?php echo __( 'Company Name:' ); ?></label>';
            companyInformation += '<input class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'company_names' ); ?>[]" type="text" value="">';
            companyInformation += '<label><?php echo __( 'Contact Email:' ); ?></label>';
            companyInformation += '<input class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'contact_emails' ); ?>[]" type="email" value="">';
            companyInformation += '</div>';
            container.append(companyInformation);
        });
    });
</script>
<?php
}
/**
 * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::update()
 *
 * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
 * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
 *
 * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
 */
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
    $instance['title'] = sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['title'] );

    // Sanitize company names and contact emails.
    $company_names = isset( $new_instance['company_names'] ) ? $new_instance['company_names'] : array();
    $contact_emails = isset( $new_instance['contact_emails'] ) ? $new_instance['contact_emails'] : array();
    $sanitized_company_names = array();
    $sanitized_contact_emails = array();
    foreach ( $company_names as $index => $company_name ) {
        $sanitized_company_names[ $index ] = sanitize_text_field( $company_name );
        $sanitized_contact_emails[ $index ] = sanitize_email( $contact_emails[ $index ] );
    }
    $instance['company_names'] = $sanitized_company_names;
    $instance['contact_emails'] = $sanitized_contact_emails;

    return $instance;
}
} // class ContactInformation_Widget
// register ContactInformation_Widget widget
function contactinformation_foo_widget() {
    register_widget( 'ContactInformation_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'contactinformation_foo_widget' );
/* Create Widget End Here */
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your 'form' function code. you are missing the button selector. just replace this line of code,

```
var addButton = container.find('.add_new_company');
```

with this one

```
var addButton = $( '.add_new_company' );
```

Comment: The "pop display that shows leave site? Changes you made may not be saved" is a problem solved when I added var addButton = $( '.add_new_company' );     but it does not allow me to add a new company, when I click on button then it should open another form to enter the details of the other company but when I click on the button nothing is happening.